# My HTML links wont take me to my other HTML files

Tags: html

I am having trouble linking my HTML pages together. My code is below. 
I have anchored the links the best way I know how to, but when I put them in HTML format and click on the hyperlink, it tells me the file cannot be found.

I have three pages I need to link together, and before I test it out, I put them all in one folder on my desktop and try to pull them up and I run into that error.

Here is my code. For ease of access, they are divided by headers of INDEX, SERVICES, and CONTACT. However, they are three separate html files.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=“en”>
<head>
<title>Trillium Media Design</title>
<meta charset=“utf-8”>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<h1>Trillium Media Design</h1>
</header>
<nav>
    <b> <a href=“index.html”>Home</a> &nbsp;
        <a href=“services.html”>Services</a> &nbsp;
        <a href=“contact.html”>Contact</a>
    </b>
</nav>
<main>
    <h2>New Media and Web Design</h2>
    <p>Trillium Media Design offers a comprehensive range of services to take your company's Web presence to the next level.</p>
    <h3>Meeting Your Business Needs</h3>
    <p>Our expert designers will listen to you as they create a website that helps to promote and grow your business.</p>
<footer>
    <small><i>Copyright &copy; 2018 Michael Vitucci</i></small></footer>
</body>
</html>

SERVICES

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=“en”>
<head>
<title>Trillium Media Design-Services</title>
<meta charset=“utf-8”>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<h1>Trillium Media Design</h1>
</header>
<nav>
    <b> <a href=“index.html”>Home</a> &nbsp;
        <a href=“services.html”>Services</a> &nbsp;
        <a href=“contact.html”>Contact</a>
    </b>
</nav>
<main>
    <h2>Our Services Meet Your Business Needs</h2>
        <dl>
            <dt><strong>Website Design></strong></dt>
                <dd>Whether your needs are large or small, Trillium can get you on the Web!</dd>
            <dt>strong>E-Commerce Solutions</strong></dt>
                <dd>Trillium offers quick entry into the e-commerce marketplace.</dd>
            <dt><strong>Search Engine Optimization</strong></dt>
                <dd>Most people find new sites using search engines. Trillium can get your website noticed.</dd>
        </dl>
<footer>
    <small><i>Copyright &copy; 2018 Michael Vitucci</i></small></footer>
</body>
</html>

CONTACT

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=“en”>
<head>
<title>Trillium Media Design-Contact</title>
<meta charset=“utf-8”>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<h1>Trillium Media Design</h1>
</header>
<nav>
    <b><a href=“index”>Home</a> &nbsp; 
        <a href=“services”>Services</a> &nbsp; 
        <a href=“contact”>Contact</a>
    </b>
</nav>
<main>
    <h2>Contact Trillium Media Design Today</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>E-Mail:
            <a href=“mailto:contact@trilliummediadesign.com”>contact@trilliummediadesign.com</a>
            </li>
            <li>Phone: 555-555-5555</li>
        </ul>
<footer>
    <small><i>Copyright &copy; 2018 Michael Vitucci</i></small></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

NEW CODE taken from browser source of Index page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=“en”>
<head>
<title>Trillium Media Design</title>
<meta charset=“utf-8”>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<h1>Trillium Media Design</h1>
</header>
<nav>
    <b> <a href="index.html">Home</a> &nbsp;
        <a href="./services.html">Services</a> &nbsp;
        <a href="/contact.html">Contact</a>
    </b>
</nav>
<main>
    <h2>New Media and Web Design</h2>
    <p>Trillium Media Design offers a comprehensive range of services to take your company's Web presence to the next level.</p>
    <h3>Meeting Your Business Needs</h3>
    <p>Our expert designers will listen to you as they create a website that helps to promote and grow your business.</p>
<footer>
    <small><i>Copyright &copy; 2018 Hannah Markel</i></small></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the browser URL I get from the Index page.

file:///C:/Users/Michael%20Vitucci/Desktop/michaeltest/michaelindex.html

This is the browser URL I get from the error page.

file:///C:/Users/Michael%20Vitucci/Desktop/michaeltest/index.html

Comment: Try to open individuals html file in browser. Let us know, they are opening or not.

Comment: They open individually in the browser.

Comment: have you tried adding `/` before the address?

Comment: Just tried that, but same result.

Answer (score 1):

You are using typographic quotation marks, while you should use double quotes (and this applies to all attributes). For example, instead of: `<a href=“index.html”>Home</a>` you should use `<a href="index.html">Home</a>`.

Comment: I just tried switching out the quotation marks, but it is still telling my the file cannot be found

Comment: @MichaelVitucci Edit your answer and paste the new code from your browser source. Also, paste here two URLs from the browser address bar: one for the current page and another for the error page.

Comment: just posted them!

Comment: You're a genius! I realize my mistake! My files were named incorrectly.

Comment: @MichaelVitucci You're welcome. By the way, you didn't replaced all typographic quotation marks ()for example, `<meta charset=“utf-8”>`. Also, instead of `/contact.html` use `contact.html`.

Answer (score 1):

check all these files are in the same directory as index.html?, else you have to mention relative path from the directory where these files are kept and if they are in same directory still issue try like "./services.html"

```
 <b> <a href="index.html">Home</a> &nbsp;
    <a href="services.html">Services</a> &nbsp;
    <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
 </b>
```

Comment: I tried adding the "./" as well as "/". That didn't work. How do I verify that they are in the same directory?

Comment: @MichaelVitucci if  *file:///C:/Users/Michael%20Vitucci/Desktop/michaeltest/index.html* index.html, please try opening the folder   *michaeltest*  and see all  .html files are placed there? incase if they not present in  *michaeltest* folder but  lets say if they present on Desktop you can try  "../michaeltest/services.html" or try relative to the directory where these files exist

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the whole address?

```html
<a href="http://www._____.com/index.html">Home</a>
```

Comment: Yes! So for the services page, I have tried replacing "services.html" with "file:///C:/Users/Michael%20Vitucci/Desktop/New%20folder/services.html" and I still get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are these files are on the same level, i.e is index.html and about.html placed in same folder if they are placed in the same folder you can directly access that file via "./about.html" from index.html file, if the files are placed in different folders at the same level, then you need to go up one level i.e "../about/about.html";

p.s to avoid any typos you can use tools like emmet for HTML, and to avoid path mismatch issues you can use extensions like path Intellisense.
(Emmet and path Intellisense are extensions available in vs code).